# Some NextJS questions regarding static/hybrid and SSR builds

Tags: next.js

So, I am new to NextJS and I understand, to some degree, the usages of getStaticProps, getServerSideProps etc... but, there are nuances of use cases that I am not wrapping my head around. I am hoping given the conditions below you could tell me what type of generation to use.

Product Page:
--- Most of it is retrieved by products ids and the data doesn't change much
--- there is some "dynamic content" but its minor. Like a % discount applied given some conditions?

which?

HomePage:
--- mostly all static.. ie reviews/ product info etc.. BUT
--- has a header (that shows on all pages) that shows users name IF they are logged in.
Which?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend understanding `getStaticProps` vs `getServerSideProps` on the fundamental level.

Sounds more complicated than it is. A simple rule is asking yourself:

1. do I want to to have the particular page generated at **build time** each time the content is changed? That means your **CI server** builds the page, I. e. your Vercel, AWS Amplify, GitHub actions, GitLab Pipelines, etc. regenerates the static page with each content change. use `getStaticProps`.

or

2. do I want to have the page generated in **real time** on each browser request by the **web server**? use `getServerSideProps`.

It's a trade off between great performance (build time) and content freshness (real time).

Next.js' strategy is to move as much rendering to static (build time) and subsequently refresh relevant content as required in a smart way. This is where the `revalidate` option comes in and a product page is a textbook use case here.

Comment: I get that, but what if 90% of the page, lets say is static. It doesn't change much, BUT there are promotional items that need upddating or are dynanic... IS it wise to use getStaticProps with some apis in useEffect to saturate the dynamic stuff? And use "revalidate" to make sure we get our updates, if needed?

Comment: you can render the promotions as a widget via XHR on the client side - provided the API is public, otherwise you'd need to shield it with api routes (or any other proxy / gateway). can work if you handle the UX with a decent loader. in my mind, the `revalidte` option is a separate strategy as it is a combination of SSR/SSG. I think we will have more options in the future (see recently announced server side components) but for now you might need to pick pick between XHR (client side), `revalidate` or full SSR. depends on the weight of various elements in your use case (UX, SEO, performance)

Answer (score 1):

I think on both pages you should use getStaticProps.
In this case 1: you use getStaticPaths to export all production pages by id. With your requirement data don't change regularly on Product page, you can use `revalidate` property to update to content or rebuild the project.

references on here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching

Comment: on Production page, you also use getServerSideProps, not different performance than getStaticProps much